# A single word for a person who doesn't know or feel the difference between pain and pleasure?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word which would define a person who doesn't know or feel the difference between pain and pleasure.

I have looked around a lot, but I am unable to find the proper word. There are words which revolves around it such hedonism , paradox of hedonism , sadist , masochism. But none make the exact sense. Masochistic, I find is the closest one, but as per it's meaning it means when your pain gives you pleasure, which is not the same sense I am looking for.

Usage of the word would something like this:

"He is a _________ , it is futile to torture him."

Comment: yes, corrected.

Comment: If you're indifferent to pain and pleasure, you're said to be *stoic.*

Comment: "*Hannah is a teen-age girl with CIPA (Congenital Insensitivity to Pain and Anhidrosis), a rare condition in which she can not feel pain, hot, or cold.*" BUT it's not a single word. :(

Comment: There is a term, something like "ahedonistic" (but not that).  But it's not coming to me just now.

Comment: [Alexithymia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexithymia) is an inability to feel emotion, presumably including pleasure. [Congenital analgesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congenital_insensitivity_to_pain) is an innate inability to feel pain.

Comment: @Autoresponder so _stoic_ could be used in the above sentence then ?

Comment: Would impassible or soulless fit your need?

Comment: @keyboard-k: Yes. Some of our high-rep users might dredge up something better, too. Do you want to add a little more context to your question?

Comment: ... *Vulcan* ...

Comment: @Autoresponder but _stoic_ , is used as adjective isn't it ?

Comment: @keyboard-k: That would be *stoical.* The noun is *stoic.*

Comment: @keyboard-k the exact sense you describe seems to be someone who could sense that pain or pleasure were being inflicted upon them but wouldn't know which.  Is this correct?

Comment: @CandiedOrange exactly !

Comment: @keyboard-k Sounds like a medical condition.  Stoics (and Vulcans) feel pain.  They just try not to show that they can.  You're not simply describing appearances right?

Comment: @CandiedOrange right, I am not describing appearances here.

Comment: If you had requested a phrase instead of a word, I would have suggested: _he is **impervious to pain**._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One who can endure pain and hardship without showing one’s feelings or complaining is said to be **"stoical"**   e.g. "A stoical or phlegmatic kind of person often underestimates pain or pleasure".

> [**stoic**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stoic) implies an apparent indifference to pleasure or especially to pain often as a matter of principle or self-discipline.
>
> - He was resolutely stoic even in adversity.
>
> That said, I think it fills the blanks: **"He is a stoic, it's futile to torture him"**

One who can't feel any pleasure is said to be **"anhedonic"**.

> [**anhedonia**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anhedonia) a psychological condition characterized by inability to experience pleasure in normally pleasurable acts
>
> - An anhedonic mother finds no joy from playing with her baby.
> - An anhedonic football fan is not excited when his team wins.
> - An anhedonic teenager feels no pleasure from passing the driving test.

**One who can feel neither pain nor pleasure**, or can't tell the difference between them suffers from a serious [**affective disorder**](http://www.healthline.com/health/affective-disorders#Overview1) or a [**neurlogic disease**](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2096434/). In the latter condition,  affected individuals are unable to feel physical pain due to mutations in a specific gene.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly *insensate*

> [**insensate**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/insensate) *adjective*:
>
> 1. lacking sensation or consciousness
>
> **2.** insensitive; unfeeling
>
> 3. foolish; senseless
>
> synonyms for **2nd** sense: unfeeling, hardened, indifferent, insensitive, thoughtless, stolid, thick-skinned, obtuse, inured, imperceptive, impercipient, unperceiving

(Collins Dictionary online)

Comment: This should have been the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly ***imperturbable***:

> : very calm : very hard to disturb or upset
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imperturbable)</sub>